# Парсинг многоуровнего JSON файла

Tags: массивы, json, swift

через запрос по апи я получаю вот такого вида файл.

```
имяКотолога{ имяКаталога{ [(ключ: ссылка), (ключ: ссылка),(ключ: ссылка)]
```

Мне нужно перенести все полученные данные в массив или кортеж. чтоб на основе него я мог использовать функцию названиеМасива.count для динамической генерации ячеек collectionView

Но у меня никак не получается. 
Напрямую обращаться к модели также нельзя.
И почему то при создании массива я не могу в него передать данные

Подскажите пожалуйста правильный синтаксис объявления такого массива и как в него передавать значение с модели

я не знаю заранее сколько у меня будет в массиве объектов

вот моя модель

```
struct Auction: Codable
let photos: [Photos]
    struct Photos: Codable {
        let photo: URL
    }
```

Comment: можете дать ссылку на запрос?

Comment: ПРоблему решил. Я просто изначально не добавил в структуру модели нужный мне класс, а пытался обратиться к нему напрямую